# Create custom validation for form entity

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms, formbuilder

I am using the form builder to create an choice-field form an entity looking like this:

```
$form->add(
                    'existing_items','entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Artikel aus',
                    'class' => 'ProjectShoppinglistBundle:Item',
                    'empty_value' => 'Bitte einen Artikel auswählen',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('item')
                            ->leftJoin('item.userItems', 'userItem')
                            ->where('userItem.user = ' . $options['attr']['id'])
                            ->orderBy('item.name', 'ASC');

                    },
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                    ),
                ));
```

but I am using jquery to change the content of the dropdown, so I need to change the validation for the field, how can I achieve that the values in the form are valid for all elements in the items-table and not just the one's which are linked to my the userId used in the query?

This is necessary for my approach because I have a second dropdown where the user can define if he wants to see the items on his own list, of other lists or all items

I have already taken a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) but I still don't really get it how I can use the eventListener to get the desired result.

If someone could give me a useful hint, I would appreciate this very much.

Comment: How does the jquery change the content of the dropdown? Please explain a bit more detailed.

Comment: The jquery fills the dropdown with items linked to other users or with all items in the Item table, but only the one linked to the original user id are valid

Comment: Why does the jquery fills the dropdown with items which aren't related to the user? When you have the requirement to use only items linked to the user?

Comment: Because I have a second dropdown where the user can define if he wants to see the items on his own list, of other lists or all items

Comment: Ahhhh ... Add these information as part of your question, so the other users don't need to read our conversation. :)